# Avoid infinite PubSub loop when Cloud Run returns an error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm building an architecture for processing files. A script run on Cloud Functions downloads it, and then a Cloud Run application processes it. Until now, the communication between Cloud Functions and Cloud Run was performed through requests. However, this has the disadvantage that the Cloud Function needs to wait until the file processing has completed. I thought on using PubSub in between: Cloud Function publishes, and Cloud Run subscribes. However, I'm facing an undesired behavior when Cloud Run returns a non `200` status code: the PubSub message keeps being resent to Cloud Run on a infinite loop.

This is how I created the PubSub topic and the Cloud Run subscription:

```
resource "google_pubsub_topic" "schema_validator_trigger" {
  name   = "oney-schema-validator-trigger"
  labels = var.tags
}

resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "schema_validator_subscription" {
  name  = "oney_schema_validator_subscription"
  topic = google_pubsub_topic.schema_validator_trigger.name

  ack_deadline_seconds = 600

  expiration_policy {
    ttl = ""
  }

  push_config {
    push_endpoint = "https://my-cloudrun-url.a.run.app/my/endpoint"
    oidc_token {
      service_account_email = google_service_account.downloader_sa.email
    }
    attributes = {
      x-goog-version = "v1"
    }
  }
}
```

Inside Cloud Run, I'm applying certain validations to check that the received PubSub message has the proper format:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/my/endpoint", methods=["POST"])
def my_endpoint():
    # Check received PubSub message
    envelope = request.get_json()

    expected_params = ["bucketname", "filename"]
    msg, status_code = utils.requests.validate_pubsub_message(envelope, expected_params)
    if status_code != 200:
        utils.logging.log_message(msg, severity="ERROR")
        return msg, status_code

    ...
```

Here is where the problem comes. If I return a `400` status code, the message keeps being resent to the endpoint no matter what, and it won't stop until I purge it from the topic.

**Desired behavior:** if my Cloud Run returns a non `200` status code, the problem is on the request. Even if my server crashes and returns a 500 status code, I would still be notified through the logs and alerting and I will work on the solution and resend the PubSub message when the fix is done. I want the PubSub message to be ACKed once the Cloud Run application provides a response, no matter its status code. Is this possible, or am I making a design error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a non-`200` status code is an indicator to Pub/Sub that the message should be redelivered. For transient failures, whether they are ones caused by something in the transport layer or in the end application itself, the response allows the service to know that redelivery is needed.

If you have a permanent failure for which you do not want the message to be redelivered, return a `200` status so it is not redelivered. If you are able to detect that these messages are bad, you might consider handling them by publishing them to another topic that acts as a dead letter topic so you can examine the requests that failed. You can also [set up this behavior within Pub/Sub itself](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/handling-failures#dead_letter_topic) so that after a desired number of failed sends, the message is moved to another topic, but the minimum number of delivery attempts is 5.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the answer, this gave me a better understanding of how PubSub is meant to be used

Comment: Something which just came to my mind: when we use a Cloud Function triggered by a Cloud Storage event, I guess this is using PubSub under the hood. How does this handle the message acknowledgement so that, if we configure it with no retries, if the Function execution fails it doesn't get triggered again?

Comment: It works by acking the message regardless of the result of the run of the Cloud Function within the Cloud Function infrastructure.